# How to bind an Enum from ViewModel to ComboBox - twoway

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding, visual-studio-2015

**[Solved]**: I have provided a working example in the answer below.

---

Related thread on [SO][1]

I have read many threads here, how to bind an enum to a combobox.
I got it to work oneway with another approach using a MarkupExtension!
But then I don't have twoway binding available.
I want to bind it to an Enum property of my ViewModel.

When I try this approach:

```
 <Window.Resources>
    <ObjectDataProvider MethodName="GetValues"
                        ObjectType="{x:Type sys:Enum}"
                        x:Key="DetailScopeDataProvider">
        <ObjectDataProvider.MethodParameters>
            <x:Type TypeName="local:DetailScope" />
        </ObjectDataProvider.MethodParameters>
    </ObjectDataProvider>
```

One further problem here is, that VS intellisense does not offer me this:

> sys:Enum

I also don't know to setup the ItemSource and SelectedValue property of the combobox.

Comment: Did you declare the `sys` namespace with an `xmlns:` attribute? Please provide a good [mcve] that reliably reproduces your problem. Most likely it's some kind of typographical error, but absent a good MCVE we can't even know for sure what mistake you've made exactly.

Comment: I resolved the sys problem. My main problem is the twoway binding. I will create an example quickly and upload it...

Comment: Because, when I enter for example some characters into a textbox they instantly get updated to the viewmodel. And when I update the viewmodel property of the textbox the view gets updated without any further coding.
The same I want for the combobox which gets its values from an enum property of the viewmodel

Comment: _"here you can download the sample project I've prepared"_ -- that's not how Stack Overflow works. As you should know, approaching 2000 rep yourself, every question must be self-contained, with a good [mcve] that reliably reproduces whatever problem or issue you're dealing with, and the information from the author of the question belongs in the question post itself, not the comments. Comments are a way for everyone else to ask you for improvements to the question, but those improvements belong in the question itself.

Comment: improved and answered! ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Ok, got it working.

The ObjectDataProvider has an ObjectType Property. As I want to use an Enum Property of my viewmodel as a datasource for the combobox.
The Object Type in this case is:

> System.Enum

which resides in the System namespace in the mscorlib assembly.
We therefore have to add import the namespace in our XAML:

> xmlns:sys="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib"

Here I will post the whole code for reference:

**Test.xaml(window):**

```
<Window x:Class="WpfTrash.Test"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfTrash"
   -->> xmlns:sys="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib" <<--
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="Test" Height="300" Width="300">
    <Window.Resources>
        <local:MyEnumToStringConverter x:Key="MyEnumConverter" />
        <ObjectDataProvider x:Key="odp" MethodName="GetNames" ObjectType="{x:Type sys:Enum}">
            <ObjectDataProvider.MethodParameters>
                <x:Type  TypeName="local:TheEnum"/>
            </ObjectDataProvider.MethodParameters>
        </ObjectDataProvider>

    </Window.Resources>
    <StackPanel>
        <TextBox x:Name="txtTheInt" Text="{Binding Path=TheInt}"/>
        <TextBox x:Name="txtTheString" Text="{Binding Path=TheString}"/>
        <!--<ComboBox x:Name="cboTheEnum" DataContext="{StaticResource SortedEnumView}" ItemsSource="{Binding}"/>-->
        <ComboBox x:Name="cboTheEnum" ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource odp}}" SelectedValue="{Binding Path=TheEnum, Converter={StaticResource MyEnumConverter}}"/>
        <Button x:Name="button" Content="Button" Click="button_Click"/>
    </StackPanel>
</Window>
```

**Test.xaml.cs**

```
namespace WpfTrash
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for Test.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class Test : Window
    {
        MyClass vm = new MyClass();
        public Test()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            this.DataContext = vm;
        }

        private void button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            var selecteditem = (TheEnum)Enum.Parse(typeof(TheEnum), cboTheEnum.SelectedItem.ToString(), true);
        }
    }
}
```

**The viewmodel:**

```
public class MyClass : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public int TheInt { get; set; }
    public string TheString { get; set; }

    TheEnum theEnum;

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    private void NotifyPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }

    public TheEnum TheEnum
    {
        get
        {
            return theEnum;
        }

        set
        {
            theEnum = value;
            NotifyPropertyChanged("TheEnum");
        }
    }
}
```

**The Enum definition:** (is not part of a class definition)

```
public enum TheEnum
{
    A, B, C, D
}
```

**The Converter:**

```
public class MyEnumToStringConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return value.ToString();
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return (TheEnum)Enum.Parse(typeof(TheEnum), value.ToString(), true);
    }
}
```